# Index Youtube videos for Google Search Appliance

Tags: youtube-api, google-search-appliance

We're successfully using the Youtube API to create a metadata-and-url xml feed that the GSA requires and pushing it to our Google Search Appliance according to the documentation

The question that we have is that we know you need to put a start url in the **Content Sources > Web Crawl > Start and Block URLs** page in the Admin Console. If we put in https://www.youtube.com as a start url and a follow pattern of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=* (which all looks like all youtube videos follow) will the GSA only index whats coming from the feed or will it go out to youtube.com and index a bunch of content that isn't part of our channel? I don't see anywhere you can specify a channel for a video.

FYI, we are aware of FishBowlSolutions connector for YouTube but trying to avoid spinning up another server with TomCat just to index our YouTube videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not add the youtube-url to your Start URLs, only to your Follow Patterns. That way, the crawler will not crawl Youtube from top to bottom, but the URLs you provide in the feed will be crawled. However, if GSA finds URLs on the crawled pages, it will obviously also crawl those. 
An option is to tighten the Follow Patterns. And of course you can develop a Youtube connector on Googles Adaptor Framework, which is not that hard for Java-developers!

Answer (score 0):

[Google CSE Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Gulx.png)
[YouTube User Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mb7vz.png)

I haven't used GSA(I'm getting ramped up on it though, which is how I found your post), but the way I've accomplished this using Google's CSE is to index the channel, user or playlist specifically, vs. youtube in general, i.e.:

youtube dot com/user/alltrapmusic

or: youtube dot com/channel/UC_ahy2GUec7EmbWF3LGxLhQ

or: youtube dot com/playlist?list=PLsHnWFR4n5jBFYdsclaKtdWQtf2Iu8bKZ

So, in CSE, I can configure to search only that user, channel and playlist and return only results found on those three (Google CSE Search link).

I can only assume GSA works the same(as I mentioned, I have no experience with GSA); if not, my apologies.

~chipleh

p.s. - in order to find your youtube channel, go to the user link(YouTube User Panel link); there you'll find home, videos, playlists, channels, etc. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Chipleh, We'll try that out.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking to use the Youtube api and push their videos to the GSA, we found that there needs to be a few changes to the feed.

The **feedtype** needs to be **full** in the xml.This tells the GSA that everything it needs to know about the content is in the xml and it doesn't need to go out and index a url.

You need to have a `<content>` node in the xml. We used the description coming from Youtube api as the value. This is what is displayed to the user in the search results

**url attribute** on the record needs to be a value that can be added to the Start and Block URL and Follow patterns in the GSA settings and it needs to be unique. These actually don't need to exist but the GSA will use this value in the xml to determine if it should be included in the index. We used a fake url and the value from Youtube video ID appended to make it unique

**displayurl** attribute will be the url that will be displayed in the results so it would have the actual youtube url.

**Start and Block URLs** should contain the general url attribute value. For us, it was the fake directory http://www.yourdomain.com/video/youtube/

**Follow Pattern** should contain the pattern to follow that also matches the Start URL. Since we only have videos in that directory, we're able to put the same value as the Start URL. If you are pointing to a real directory and have other content in that that you don't want to index, you may need to add whatever pattern is common to your videos.

A sample record is below. Once we updated our feed, added the Start and Block URLs, our videos appear in our search results.

```
<gsafeed>
    <header>
        <datasource>youtube</datasource>
        <feedtype>full</feedtype>
    </header>
    <group action="add">
        <record url="http://www.yourdomain.com/video/youtube/?VIDEOID" displayurl="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEOID" mimetype="text/html">
            <content><![CDATA[DESCRIPTION]]></content>
            <metadata>
                <meta name="Title" content="TITLE OF VIDEO"></meta>
                <meta name="Published" content="2016-08-15T22:00:38.000Z"></meta>
                <meta name="PhotoURL" content="https://i.ytimg.com/.."></meta>
            </metadata>
        </record>
</group>
</gsafeed>
```